# Is there an Aztec barcode generator library for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, barcode, mobile-webkit, aztec-barcode

I'm looking for an open source image generation script for Aztec (2D) barcodes:

[image: Aztec Barcode]

I can't seem to find any available scripts out there.

There is an Active-X control [here](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/barcodesdk/bytescoutbarcodesdk_first_step_with_javascript.html) that can be used only in IE and an image generator URL [here](http://www.bcgen.com/aztec-barcode-creator.html), but these are not useful as it should be a **pure javascript solution** running under webkit-based browsers that can run in disconnected mode for mobile apps.

Anyone have some old code for this hanging around either written in javascript or that can be ported to javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[bwip-js](https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js) runs in any browser that supports `<canvas>` – IE 9+, FF 2+, Chrome, Safari 3+, Opera 9+, and Android 2.1+. It also runs server-side in Node.  (If you wanted downlevel IE support, try using a [`<canvas>` emulation layer](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/).)

Aztec is among the 83 barcode formats it can draw.  [Here's a demo of it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/tAaBe/).

Comment: It seems to work for server side JS (node) but does it work for client side JS?

Comment: Yes, any browser that supports `<canvas>` works.  See *demo.html* in the download ZIP.

Comment: I see an POST request to the server in FireBug and a hard result to an image on the server...

Comment: You clicked [this link](http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/generator/), which is a demo of the [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) [implementation](http://code.google.com/p/postscriptbarcode/) that bwip-js is based on.  [Download the bwip-js ZIP](http://code.google.com/p/bwip-js/downloads/list) and look at *demo.html* in that file.

Comment: I tried it already, there are errors everywhere (FF 10 on WIN 7).

Comment: Works fine for me on Win 7 with Chrome 18, FF 10, and IE 9.  (Perhaps an issue with running the file from disk (`file:///...`) instead of over http?)

Comment: ...[threw it up as a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/tAaBe/), see if that works for you.

Comment: It works! Great library by the way! Is it yours? I'm currently working on some canvas image merging stuff...

Comment: Nope.  Just a cool (and completely unnoticed) library I found.